# SSRS report join datasets according parameter values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have different dataset . Each for a country (USA,FRANCE,BRITAIN etc.) . 
Also i have a Report multi value parameter to select country , so the report will show data only from the selected countries. 
Several questions:
1. How can i join (merge) different datasets as described below?
2. I need to have a table in the report with the Country Column .

Comment: Please clarify, You have multiple datasets each one for one country. So you want to the report uses the datasets according to parameter selection, right?

Comment: Exactly. and join these datasets into a table

Comment: You can display only one **detailed** dataset in a tablix item, multiple datasets require aggregation of rows. Regarding to parameter you can have one parameter to show users, then based on that parameter selection populate _behind the scenes_ other parameters each for a country dataset.

Comment: I don't have a common value shared in all datasets that i can use for the LookUp Function

Comment: How about a #temp table that your datasets populate then a final datsaset that gets the selected countries from your #temp table?

Comment: You mean using LINKED SERVERS? i can't do it and can't add LINKED servers. If not, how can i Union the datasets into the temp table?

Comment: OK - I didn't know you didn't have access.

Answer (score 0):

How about a table with separate tables for each country?

Create the table you want for a **country** (I'll C1 from here).

Create another table (T1) with cells the **same width** as C1. Delete the **DATA** row. Add a new row for your country. Merge the cells from the new row.

Put the headers from C1 on T1 and delete the header from C1. Put C1 into T1's single merged cell.

Copy C1 to create a new country and add a new line and repeat for all countries - changing the dataset for the new country.

Use the table row's **visibility** to show that country of not based on your parameter.

[image]

I think I've done this once a while back.

Comment: Nice idea. but when i insert the table C1 into T1 merged row , it changes the dataset of C1 same as the dataset of T1...So i can't use different datasets (datasources)

Comment: I can't think of another way to do it since you can't merge your data beforehand. Maybe just making one table with just the headers and separate tables without headers (just a detail line) stacked on top of each other? Then use visibility to show/hide them? It'll look like one table. You couldn't sort or sum them normally though.